# How to use CSS selector to find link by text

Tags: jquery, css, selenium

I am using Java and Selenium to look at a page to see if there is a link with specific text and if not then I go to the next page and check.

My problem is that I can't find a way to find a link based on it's text, I can find them based on their URL but text doesn't seem to work.

This is what I do for the URL:

```
$("a[href*='foo']")
```

But when I try the same for text:

```
$("a[text*='bar']")
```

It finds nothing.

The only way I know to do this is to get all of the links and loop through them checking to see if the text contains the string I am searching for.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't perform matches to text using CSS selectors.

You can use xpath:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'bar')]
```

or

```
//a[text() = 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

While there's no css pseudo selector available for the content of an element, JQUERY implements the `:contains` in its selector:

```
$('a:contains("bar")')
```

[**Jquery :contains() Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: jQuery isn't a standard!

Comment: I'm sorry @Arran, but what do you mean?

Comment: You should use **native** methods like below so that Selenium can handle it all for you. Selenium will ensure that a given selector works, in some way, on a given browser. This is going against the API and against the CSS specification.

Comment: Okay @Arran, even if it's better to use native methods, you can use jquery's implemented selectors (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815625/contains-selector-with-selenium-and-select2) You'll just have to execute it first with `JavaScriptExecutor`. So this answer is correct, after all.

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: "Wrong" is debatable. This is poor development and shouldn't have been accepted.

Comment: I agree that it shoudn't be accepted as right answer. But I also don't think that it should be downvoted.

Comment: Your advice here is seriously flawed. It works, but it's not a good technical solution to his problem. Nothing more and nothing less. If the answer is not fit for purpose, it's not a good answer.

Comment: According to https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors you can use 'a:contains("string")' directly in selenium.  No need for jQuery.  Has anyone tried?